# How to "alt-tab" out of full-screen Virt Manager?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, virt-manager

I'd like to switch from fullscreen in qemu/kvm Virt Manager back to the most recently used window on the main host's operating system (just like `alt`-`tab`), but I haven't yet found a solution that works. `ctrl`+`alt`+`f` doesn't work (it just launches an application inside the virtual machine).

I don't want to exit fullscreen mode, rather I would like to `alt-tab` back into the host and have the option to `alt-tab` back into the full-screen virtual machine.

Comment: Try Ctrl-A C and  Ctrl-A X

Comment: that just does a `select all` in the virtual machine and then hits `c` or `x` after- so doesn't work.

Comment: See if there is the equivalent of VMware Tools for the Guest and then just move between Guest and Host with the Mouse. That does work in VMware and MAY work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the keyboard-mouse access back to your host. This means that the keybindings and cursor you move will be handled by host, not by your VM. [See here for instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107633/how-do-i-get-my-mouse-back-from-qemu-kvm).

Now when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will act on the host, ie, change windows on the host. If you want to work on the VM, you'll need to give access back to the VM. In many programs, it is as simple as clicking on the VM